# HP All-In-One Printer Driver issue - Can't uninstall

Tags: drivers

I've just bought a second hand HP zv6000 laptop. In good condition, but installed files for the HP All-In-One printer drivers have been manually deleted. It doesn't show up on the add/remove software, and when I try to reinstall, it comes back with the message that the latest version is already installed. Is it possible to fully unistall the drivers (for a HP PSC2335 printer manually?

Comment: State your operating system, please.

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have a driver CD for that printer?

If so you can go to `YOUR_CD_DRIVE:util\ccc` and find the file that includes "L3 Uninstaller" or something similar.  There should also be an L1-L4.  You could probably be safe with the L1 or L2, but definitely do not use the L4.

If you don't, you can download the driver file from [HP Support](http://hp.com/support), which should come in a self-extracting file.  You'd then find where it was extracted, usually to "HP" or "Hewlett Packard" in your temp folder (which you can open by typing `%temp` into an address bar in Explorer), then the name of the print driver.  From here, you can go to the same L3 Uninstaller in `util\ccc`.

Sorry I can't be more clear, but they don't seem to have any kind of naming standard for their driver files, or to where they're extracted, so it's about the best I can do.

Comment: I tried finding the page on HP support for your printer, but I couldn't find a 2335.  Here's a link to the 2355, maybe it's similar: http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&lang=en&product=422000&